# How to use window in FFT

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I dont understand how to use the window in FFT. I use C# with Aforge.Math. I use this:

```
Array[i] = new Complex(buffer, 0);
Array[i].Re *= 0.5 * (1 - Math.Cos((2 * Math.PI * i) / 4097));
//Hanning window
```

After this:

```
FourierTransform.FFT(Array, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);
```

And If I understood correctly, what is doing this window, that code gives me bad results. Please explain me, what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you give more details about the `bad results` this code gives you? In which way they differ from the wanted results?

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you are applying the window function ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code working by using `FourierTransform.Direction.Backward`.